# Call out certain loop on Imacros?

Tags: imacros

After every 30 loops how would I be able to make it wait 2 minutes before continuing again?

```
VERSION BUILD=8300326 RECORDER=FX
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
TAB T=1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Like<SP>Video
WAIT SECONDS=5
TAB T=2
WAIT SECONDS=2
FRAME F=0
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=ID:watch-like
TAB T=2
WAIT SECONDS=4
TAB T=1
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
WAIT SECONDS=14
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SET longWait EVAL("('{{!LOOP}}' % 30 == 0) ? 120 : 0")
WAIT SECONDS={{longWait}}
```